# Modify Spring message text without restarting application?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, message

I am doing a Spring web application. I use Spring 3.1 and Eclipse. I run the application via Jetty within Eclipse.

I have many JSP pages that contain text such as this:

```
<spring:message code="label.subject"/>
```

This type of text comes from a file called messages_en.properties defined in Spring context:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
<property name="basenames">
<list>
<value>messages</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

I need to constantly modify the text in messages_en.properties. However, new text does not show up in the application without restarting Jetty, which is quite inconvenient to me.

How can I modify Spring message text without restarting Jetty?

Thanks for your help!

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in [ResourceBundleMessageSource's documentation itself](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html): use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
  <property name="basenames">
    <list>
      <value>messages</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, something built within Spring. Thanks!

Comment: i used your config in Eclipse (juno) + Jetty 8.1.2 + Java 7, it appears not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Let me guess... You're editing the messages.properties under src/, not target/? I've just tried replicating your setup and made this mistake.

Comment: Also, when dealing with problems like these ("why the hell doesn't it work?!") it helps to set log level of the Spring packages involved (in this case: `org.springframework.context.support`) to DEBUG to see what's happening inside.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in many ways. You can monitor your files for change with a file monitor and reload the resource programmatically. You can take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Basically the idea would be upon starting your app to register a file monitor on your resource and then when you change it, just reinitialize your resource.